# How Do We Test Direct Boot?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

According to [the N Developer Preview documentation](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/direct-boot.html#testing), we can set up Direct Boot support on Android N through Settings > Developer Options > Convert to file encryption. I cannot find this option on a Nexus 6 running NDP2, nor on an NDP2 emulator.

According to that same documentation, we can also set this up by running `adb reboot-bootloader` and `fastboot --wipe-and-use-fbe` in a terminal window. [This bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206757) suggests that this too is broken, along with the first option.

So, how do we test this? Specifically:

- Has anyone gotten either of the above options to work, on a device or emulator?
- Has anyone tried the "emulated Direct Boot mode" (`adb shell sm set-emulate-fbe true`), and does that work? And did you try that on a device or emulator?
- Are there any any known side effects of trying this stuff (e.g., you're likely to brick your device)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It only works on 6P and 5X, via dev options. The '--wipe-and-use-fbe' option seems not be available yet. FBE appears to work OK, you can always format userdata to revert.

Comment: Ah, that would explain why I wasn't seeing it. Too bad the emulator does not emulate this. Many thanks!

Comment: How we can confirm that my nexys device is file encrypted.

Comment: --wipe-and-use-fbe isn't working under Windows at the moment :(